# Htaccess and enbaling seo urls in opencart not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I had enabled the SEO URL`s but for some reason it is not working out, I have made htaccess file. The code is below:-

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]

RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]

RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteBase`< --- 
Where is your site? Is it in root web folder (often public_html or www) or a subfolder; like /cart or /shop?

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
```

(if your site is in public_html or www)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /shop
```

(if your site is in /shop)

Also, the default htaccess file for opencart is htaccess.txt, *make sure* you have renamed it to **.htaccess** on your server, else Apache cannot read it.